# Pandas - How to identify `nan` values in a Series

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently playing with Kaggle Titanic dataset (train.csv)

1. I can load the data fine.
2. I understood that some data in `Embarked` column has `nan` value. But when I tried to filter it using the following code, I am getting an empty array

```
    import pandas as pd
    df = df.read_csv(<file_loc>, header=0)
    df[df.Embarked == 'nan']
```

I tried to import `numpy.nan` to replace the string `nan` above. But it doesn't work.

**What am I trying to find** - is all the cells which are not 'S', 'C', 'Q'.

**Also realised later that....** the `nan` is a Float type using `type(df.Embarked.unique()[-1])`. Could someone help me understand how to identify those `nan` cells?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NaN` is used to represent missing values.

- To find them, use [`.isna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html)

  > Detect missing values.
- To replace them, use [`.fillna(value)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html)

  > Fill NA/NaN values

Some examples on a series called `col`:

```
>>> col
0    1.0
1    NaN
2    2.0
dtype: float64
>>> col[col.isna()]
1   NaN
dtype: float64
>>> col.index[col.isna()]
Int64Index([1], dtype='int64')
>>> col.fillna(-1)
0    1.0
1   -1.0
2    2.0
dtype: float64
```

---

Note that you can’t compare equality with `nan` as by definition it’s not equal to anything, not even itself:

```
>>> np.nan == np.nan
False
```

This is likely the property that is used to identify `nan` under the hood:

```
>>> col != col
0    False
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool
```

But it’s better (more readable) to use the pandas functions than to test for inequality yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the v1.5 pandas introduced some news related to this topic.

As mentioned in the [official documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/missing_data.html)

pandas missing placeholder should be 
but there are [some corner cases](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/32265) in which `np.nan` create problems.

```
> A = pd.Series([0.1, 0, None], dtype="Float32")
> A

0     0.1
1     0.0
2    <NA>
dtype: Float32
```

You cannot assign `nan` to it, it will be translated into `<NA>`

```
> A[0] = np.nan
> A

0    <NA>
1     0.0
2    <NA>
dtype: Float32
```

The `.isna()`, as explained before, is supposed to find all NA values.

```
> A.isna()

0     True
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool
```

But pandas can sometimes introduce the `np.nan` if there are computation problems.

```
> A/A
Out[20]: 
0    <NA>
1     NaN
2    <NA>
dtype: Float32
```

And it doesn't feed well the `.isna()`

```
> (A/A).isna()

0     True
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool
```

But you can count on the different equality behavior:

```
> pd.NA == pd.NA
<NA>

> np.nan == np.nan
False
```